# Firefox toolbar execution time and memory profiling

Tags: profiling, firebug, firefox-addon

So, I am working on creating a toolbar for firefox. It currently sucks as far as memory usage/execution time of the JS code I have written. I can say that since every so often firefox complains - "A script in mycode.js is taking more time than expected. Do you want to stop the script". I need to see which function is it thats doing this. Moreover, I need to see how much is the memory usage of the code I have written.

I tried using Firebug but it would tell me the speed of execution of scripts in a webpage. As you can see, my case is a bit different. Any ideas?

-thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can see if chromebug works for you:
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug_User_Guide